# Should I delete statement from my thesis?

Tags: bachelor

On my bachelor's thesis' frontpage, I wrote this sentence: "submitted by [my name] in partial fulﬁlment of the requirements for the degree of Bachelor in Computer Technology".

I had someone review my thesis and they told me that they never saw that. My thesis is worth 30 ECTS credits and I have to get 180 ECTS credits for my bachelor. They made mistakes with my thesis' contents (or my sources are wrong) so I'm wondering whether or not they're right. Is this sentence wrong and should I erase it and why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No one here can answer this. It depends entirely on your university. Every university has different requirements for formatting and what is required. Check with your university

Comment: Ask your advisor or look at a previous thesis. It might be standard some places. For publication, it is up to you to include it (perhaps as a footnote) or not.

Comment: My university doesn't have any guidelines about this. Their guidelines are less formal. I was wondering whether or not it was factually acceptable. Without this (i.e. with only "submitted by [my name] in fulﬁlment of the requirements for the degree of Bachelor in Computer Technology"), would it mean "complete fullfillment"?

Comment: Are you asking about the word "partial" (as your last comment suggests) or the sentence as a whole (as the question itself suggests)? In the former case, yes, keeping the sentence but omitting the word "partial" would imply that the thesis itself is the only requirement for your degree, which is factually incorrect. But deleting the sentence entirely is a different matter.

Comment: I wanted to know if I should delete the word "formal", the whole sentence or nothing.

Comment: the original sentence does not contain the word "formal"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My university doesn't have any guidelines about this. Their guidelines are less formal.

Then it doesn't matter too much.  It's a matter of personal preference.  Include it if you want, or omit it.

> I was wondering whether or not it was factually acceptable.

Well, yes, it is factually correct.  But if you leave it out, no one will assume it means complete fullfillment, simply because the vast majority of all degrees require both coursework and thesis.

Comment: I assumed it. I asked this question because the proofreader said that I should avoid it.